# Recursive unversion files in subversion without deleting them from the working copy

Tags: svn

I need to recursively unversion all *.pdf files in subversion

But want to keep them in the working copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use `delete` with the `--keep-local` option, and then `commit`.

On Windows

```
for /R . %1 in (*.pdf) do svn delete "%1" --keep-local
```

On Linux

```
find ./ -name "*.pdf" -type f | xargs svn delete --keep-local
```

And if you want to ignore them:

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores "*.pdf" .
```